# Getting document height with Dart?

Tags: css, dart

I'll say upfront that I feel like a total newb asking this. I've scoured the Dart docs, and googled this as much as I can. No answers. Been writing in JS for a while. Trying to get a handle on Dart.

How do you get the height of the document?

```
window.document.height
```

and

```
document.height
```

work just fine in the Dartium console.

However, when used in my code, I get this thrown

```
NoSuchMethodException : method not found: 'get:height'
```

What am I doing wrong here? And if you please, why is it wrong? What am I misunderstanding about the structure?

Thanks

Comment: How do you use it in your code?

Answer (score 1):

I'm still trying out dart, but you can use a future to get the computed height of the body:

```
  document.body.rect.then((ElementRect value){
     print(value.offset.height);    
  });
```

This should work.

The document doesn't contain any "height" in the publics neither in the Attributes map.

Comment: Since this is the body element you can just use 'document.body.rect...' saves you a query step.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am actually trying to set the height of the body, based on the height of the document (goal: 100% height honored on children). Another gentleman posted an answer here (then deleted it for some reason) where he suggested using window.innerHeight/Width. That actually works just fine. Is there a reason why your solution will work better?